# How do you write the sines of a binary expansion as an infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Consider the binary expansion:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n} $$

Now compare that to the sine of the above series:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin \left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right) $$

The above is clearly wrong because $\sin(\frac{1}{2}) +  \sin(\frac{1}{4}) +\ldots$ is not how sines are summed.

If you want to add up a series of sines you would have to use:

$$\sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a)$$

or on the unit circle:

$$\sin(a)\sqrt{1-\sin(b)^2}+\sin(b)\sqrt{1-\sin(a)^2}$$

and then in the context of the binary expansion:

$$\sin\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\sqrt{1-\sin\left(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)^2}+\sin\left(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\sqrt{1-\sin\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)^2}$$

How do you write it as an infinite series?

[Edit]
To clarify: The above cannot be written as a simple sum of terms (in $\Sigma$ notation), as far as I know, because the $n$ and $n+1$ alternates with each term. If there is a way to write it in $\Sigma$ notation, that would answer my question. Alternatively (as is the case with the currently accepted answer), if the sine summation is placed on the complex plane and a series can be expressed as the sum or product of terms that would also solve my problem.

$\sin(\Sigma...)$ is not wrong but I need a series like $\sin(\frac{1}{2^n})...$ to cross out some of the terms during simplification to arrive at a closed form.

The following is beyond the scope of the question but might shed some light on what I need this for: I use a constant for $\sin(\frac{1}{2})$ and then calculate $[\sin(\frac{1}{4}),\sin(\frac{1}{8})...]$ by halving the angle. I then add up a combination of these terms, determined by binary conversion, to arrive at the sine of the relevant angle. I do it that way to escape some of the limitations of the unit circle. I already do this successfully but need the math notation for it.

I understand that this is unusual, so please be patient with me; I'm a programmer, not a mathematician.

Comment: What does $\sum =\frac 1 {2^{n}}$ mean?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8}...$

Comment: Is your question how to express $\sin \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \right)$ in terms of $\sin(\frac{1}{2^n})$ ?

Comment: @MartinR yes, you could say that.

Comment: $\sin \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \right) = \sin(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it as an infinite product.

$$\sin\left(\sum2^{-n}\right)=\Im\left(e^{i\sum2^{-n}}\right)=\Im\left(\prod e^{i2^{-n}}\right)=\Im\left(\prod(\cos2^{-n}+i\sin2^{-n})\right).$$

Comment: Ah, that's more like it! Could you please explain what $\Im$ is though?

Comment: @dataphile: the imaginary part.